# Where is spellout rule(RuleBasedNumberFormat) of ICU library?

Tags: c++, icu

I use ICU to spell out number to string like :
"one hundred and thirty-four" // 134 using en_US spellout
the out of box spellout rule for my locale(vi_VN) is seem wrong
15 become "mười năm" instead of "mười lăm" and many more wrong
so I need to edit the rule but don't know where to change

Comment: I can format the num with rule directly using C++ API but I need make change to the rule in icudt48l.dat file so I need to know where to edit it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ICU data comes from CLDR. Please file a bug in CLDR, https://cldr.unicode.org - If you have trouble, let me know.

Ideally you would download CLDR source and rebuild ICU data from CLDR.  CLDR uses a slightly different format for rules.

But, if you want to make a patch, you can download ICU from Subversion, and the data will be in the icu/source/data/rbnf directory.

Hope this helps, and please do file a bug in CLDR. There's no reason to file the bug in ICU, ICU will pick up the fixed data automatically.

(I work on both ICU and CLDR)

Comment: Thanks for point out CLDR, I will test the rule first and make a change request later to CLDR

Comment: @NhuPhuong there's actually a tester app here:  http://st.unicode.org/cldr-apps/numbers.jsp

Comment: neat site ^^, really helpful

Comment: I think you mean to say the data is in the icu/source/data/rbnf directory.

Comment: @NightOwl888 right you are! Fixed